# Do something (alert) when all the stuff has finished fading in

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I'm trying to figure out how I can do something (alert) when all the stuff has finished fading in. Maybe my syntax is not good?

```
    $.fn.showdelay = function(){
            var delay = 0;
            return this.each(function(){
                $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(200);
                delay += 200;
            },
            function(){ 
                alert('done!');
            });
        };
    $item.delay(500).showdelay();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize the `callback function parameter` in the `fadeIn` method:

```
$.fn.showdelay = function(){
        var delay = 0, count = $(this).length - 1;

        return this.each(function(i){
            $(this).delay(delay).fadeIn(200, function() {
                if(i == count) alert('something');
            });
            delay += 200;
        });
    };
$item.delay(500).showdelay();
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fadeIn()` callback which will run when the animation finishes.

```
$('#el').fadeIn('fast', function(){ //Callback });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback method provided in fadeIn.

```
$.fn.showdelay = function() {
var delay = 0;
return this.each(function(){
    $(this).fadeIn(200, function() { 
        alert('done!'); 
    });
    delay += 200;
});
$item.delay(500).showdelay();
```